# lenovo ideapad slim 3 Laptop fingerprint reader is not recognized in Ubuntu 20.04? (ELAN:Fingerprint)

Tags: drivers, lenovo, fingerprint-reader, ideapad

I've tried `fprintd-enroll` then spits out `Impossible to enroll: GDBus.Error:net.reactivated.Fprint.Error.NoSuchDevice: No devices available`

Any ideas how to make this work?

is there Linux driver for this fingerprint reader ?

out put of : `lsusb`

```
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 04f3:0c4b Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:Fingerprint**
```

out put : `systemctl status fprintd.service`

```
fprintd.service - Fingerprint Authentication Daemon
   
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/fprintd.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2022-04-04 12:42:31 +0530; 2s ago
     Docs: man:fprintd(1)
 Main PID: 9018 (fprintd)
    Tasks: 5 (limit: 14040)
   Memory: 1.6M
   CGroup: /system.slice/fprintd.service
         └─9018 /usr/libexec/fprintd

 අප්‍රි 04 12:42:31 user-IdeaPad-3 systemd[1]: Starting Fingerprint Authentication Daemon...
 අප්‍රි 04 12:42:31 user-IdeaPad-3 systemd[1]: Started Fingerprint Authentication Daemon.
```

Comment: Hello. What kernel version are you running?

Comment: thank for the reply. kernel : Linux 5.13.0-39-generic x86_64

Comment: You may be better off switching to a generic-hwe kernel. Here is some info on kernels for you. https://ubuntu.com/kernel/variants

Answer (score 2):

How to enable 0c4b ELAN FingerPrint Driver for Ubuntu 22.04 64bit.
A common fingerprint reader on Lenovo laptops.

Confirm the device in a terminal.

```
$ lsusb |grep Elan
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04f3:0c4b Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:Fingerprint
```

or

```
$ hwinfo | grep Fingerprint
Device: usb 0x0c4b "ELAN:Fingerprint"
```

After confirming your device is the 0c4b, download the drive from the Lenovo support site.

Google search: "ELAN FingerPrint Driver for Ubuntu 22.04 - ThinkPad E14 Gen ..."

or

use the following link:
https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds560939-elan-fingerprint-driver-for-ubuntu-2204-thinkpad-e14-gen-4-e15-gen-4

Download the driver "ELAN FingerPrint Driver r1slf01w.zip"

The site will ask for a serial number on the first try, ignore this by clicking cancel on the pop-up screen & click download again.
On the second try it will download the zip file without the popup asking for a serial number.

Extract the zip file & open a terminal in the extracted folder. The only contents of the folder should be "libfprint-2-tod1-elan.so".

In the terminal:

(Assumed location of download, may be different on your system)

```
$ cd ~/Download/r1slf01w/libfprint-2-tod1-elan_0.0.8_Ubuntu22.04
```

(best practice before any new install of applications)

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

(This installs the fprint library & ssl tools. Note that libssl3 should already be installed on Ubuntu 22.04 fresh install, so may be no need to install libssl3)

```
$ sudo apt install libfprint-2-tod1 libssl3
```

(Create a directory for the system to access the driver)

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfprint-2/tod-1/
```

(Copy the driver into the new folder)

```
$ sudo cp libfprint-2-tod1-elan.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfprint-2/tod-1/
```

(Restart the fprint service to load the new driver)

```
$ sudo systemctl restart fprintd.service
```

(Exit the terminal)

```
$ exit
```

Go to settings, select "Users" & enable "fingerprint login".
Click the marker to the right of "Enabled" & Enroll fingerprints.

Comment: Can confirm that it works on Ubuntu 23.10 as well.